# Use vue router (v4) in a plain .js file with Quasar framework (v2)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-router4

I'm trying to access the router from a plain .js file in a Quasar project but I'm not being able to. I have search how to do it in vue and people seem to import the `Router` object from `/src/router/index`, like this: `import { Router } from 'src/router/index'`.

But Quasar doesn't expose the `Router` object, but a function called `route` that accepts another function as an argument that returns the `Router` object.

```
export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
    const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
        ? createMemoryHistory
        : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history'
        ? createWebHistory
        : createWebHashHistory;

    const Router = createRouter({
        scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
        routes,

        // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
        // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
        // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
        history: createHistory(process.env.MODE === 'ssr' ? void 0 : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE),
    });
    return Router;
});
```

How can I use the `Router` object outside a SFC with Quasar?

Answer (score 10):

Ideally, you shouldn't need the router outside Vue components, outside boot files, outside `src/router/index.js`, outside `src/store/index.js`, and except the places where you define a function that gets called in Vue files(*e.g. composables/helpers*). Here are all the ways to access the router, both inside and outside SFCs:

**Inside `.vue` files:**

- Composition API(*inside setup() or `<script setup>`*): `const router = useRouter()`
- Options API: `this.$router`
- Inside the `<template>` section: `@whatever="$router.push('...')"`

**Inside boot files:**

```js
// src/boot/whatever.js
export default boot(({ router }) => {
  router.beforeEach(...)
})
```

**Inside `src/router/index.js`(*using boot files are better*):**

```js
const router = createRouter(...)

router.beforeEach(...)
```

**Inside a function/composable that you use in .vue files:**

```js
// /src/composables/whatever.js
export function useWhatever() {
  const router = useRouter()

  // ...

  function changeRoute () {
    router.push('...')
  }

  return {
    changeRoute,
    // ...
  }
}

// Inside setup() or <script setup>
const { changeRoute } = useWhatever()
changeRoute()
```

**As a last resort / lazy way (*won't work with SSR*):**

```js
// src/router/index.js
// Remove export default function route(...), and use it like this:
const router = createRouter(...)
export default router;

// src/whatever.js
import router from 'src/router';

router.push('...');
```